# Add a language filter to stackexchange.com tag filters

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, languages, tag-filters

The [filtered questions page on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/filters) is pretty useful for following topics across different sites. But since the introduction of SE sites in different languages, certain kinds of filters are less useful. As long as you filter by site, nothing changes. But if you only filter by tag, e.g. because you're interested in a specific technology no matter if it is posted on SO, DBA, Software Engineering or any other small SE site, you might now also get results in portugese or russian. I don't speak either of those languages, so those results are not useful to me.

So, in addition to the filters for sites and tags, I'd like to have a language filter. This would allow users to only query for questions in languages they actually speak, without having to provide an explicit list of site.